# CX_Freeze with tkinter gui

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I am using cxfreeze to make an executable of my tkinter gui. I have some buttons and text inputs where I am able to interact with my program on the gui, but it seems as if nothing happens when I try to run the actual program behind the gui.

Would anyone know why I can run the gui on its own and it works just fine, but when the gui is opened as an executable, it loses all functionality. Can this be an issue of not all dependencies being taken care of?

Hi I am making this edit to show my tkinter file and setup file to hopefully help debug.

Setup.py

```
import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

include_files = [(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll')),
                 (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll'))]

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "includes": ["tkinter"], "include_files": include_files}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\tcl\tk8.6'

setup(  name = "Screenshotter",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "URL Screenshot Utility",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("screenshot_gui.py", base=base)])
```

Gui.py

```
import random
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry, IntVar, StringVar, DISABLED, NORMAL, END, W, E, Radiobutton
from tkinter import filedialog
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
from screenshotter import collect_png

class ScreenshotGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("URL Screenshotter")

        self.message = "Please enter a url and select a folder to save the screenshots"
        self.label_text = StringVar()
        self.label_text.set(self.message)
        self.label = Label(master, textvariable=self.label_text)
        self.folder = None

        vcmd = master.register(self.validate) # we have to wrap the command
        self.entry = Entry(master)

        self.select_folder = Button(master, text="Select Folder", command=self.get_filename)
        self.enter_button = Button(master, text="Run", command=self.run, state=NORMAL)

        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)
        self.entry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)

        self.selector = IntVar()
        self.button0 = Radiobutton(master, text="All Pages", variable=self.selector, value=0)
        self.button1 = Radiobutton(master, text="Main Pages", variable=self.selector, value=1)
        self.button2 = Radiobutton(master, text="Just this page", variable=self.selector, value=2)
        self.button0.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.button1.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.button2.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.select_folder.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.enter_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

    def get_filename(self):
        self.folder = filedialog.askdirectory()

    def validate(self, new_text):
        return True

    def run(self):
        self.url = str(self.entry.get())
        try:
            urlopen(self.url)
        except Exception as e:
            self.message = "Please enter a valid url\nFull Error:\n" + e
            self.label_text.set(self.message)
            return

        if not self.folder:
            self.message = "Please select a save folder"
            self.label_text.set(self.message)
            return

        self.select_folder.configure(state=DISABLED)
        self.enter_button.configure(state=DISABLED)
        while True:
            try:
                collect_png(self.url, self.folder, self.selector.get())
                break
            except:
                pass

root = Tk()
my_gui = ScreenshotGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here are the modules I include in my scipt file as well

```
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import urllib
import imgkit
from time import sleep
```

Comment: Most likely you are missing some modules but it is too vague to be answered. You will need to show your setup.py and probably a simplified version of your code too.